# Serverless Domain Manager Error: Unable to fetch information about uat-api.mydomain.com

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

i want to use custom domain name for my lambda api. i found plugin [serverless-domain-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-domain-manager).
what i  did is

1. install plugin ,
2. create custom domain name in aws/ api gateway :uat-api.mydomain.com
3. create a dns record with point to my custom-domain name
4. add custom confige to serverless.yml file

> ```
>  custom:
>         customDomain:
>         domainName: uat-api.mydomain.com
>         basePath: api
>         certificateName: som-cert-name.com
>         certificateArn: arnid
>         createRoute53Record: true
>         endpointType: ‘regional’
>         securityPolicy: tls_1_2
>         apiType: rest
>         autoDomain: false
>         hostedZoneId: Z1I1XQT4F25333
> ```

No when i run sls create_domain i got error:

```
[AWS apigatewayv2 403 3.044s 0 retries] getDomainName({ DomainName: ‘uat-api.mydomain.com’ })

  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Unable to fetch information about uat-api.mydomain.com
      at APIGatewayWrapper.<anonymous> (/Users/../node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/src/aws/api-gateway-wrapper.js:112:27)
      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at rejected (/../node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/src/aws/api-gateway-wrapper.js:6:65)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

So , whats wrong and does i miss something?

Comment: I ran into this issue. Set `SLS_DEBUG=*` and check those logs. In my case, it was because I needed to add API Gateway access to my IAM user.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's the configuration provided on the npm/github readme, but frankly it seems like overkill.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: 'test.****.io'
    basePath: 'somePath'
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

This is the configuration I use - the domain is hosting in Route53 but otherwise I don't need to mess with the AWS console at all when I create a new subdomain (in this case **create_domain** did everything).

Comment: Thanx mcatee but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Seifolah is your DNS record hosted with Route 53 or is it on a non-AWS service?

Comment: @mactee yes, it hosted on Route53. also i created a custom domain in APi Gateway manually .I thought  it may be a permission problem so granted full permission on Route53 ,Cloudfront ,... but didn't help. My Important question is what i should to de on aws side before run sls create_domain?

Comment: @Seifolah when you say you created a custom domain: had you created uat-api.mydomain.com or just mydomain.com?

Comment: i have mydomain.com as a Hosted Zone and also have uat-api.mydomain.com as A Record in mydomain.com hosted zone. dns record is alias  to my custom domain in api gateway[uat-api.mydomain.com ].
what thing that me be notable is that in Route53 i have nothing in Registered Domain !

Answer (score 0):

The AWS IAM user that using for sls deploy is not able to access the API Gateway info. You need to add that

ERROR:
User is not authorized to perform apigateway::GET on resource